# How dou you connect to a Windows IPC$ with MacOS

Tags: macos, command-line, software-recommendation, homebrew, smb

Once upon a time, OSX had samba, so you could do this:

```
 smbclient -W domain //pc-233/ipc\$ -U admin -c '' 2>&1
```

and it would tell you the remote OS or you could run other commands.

This doesn't seem possible with smbutil, and I don't see anything like rpcclient either. I checked homebrew and I don't see any replacements.

What tools exist on macOS that would allow partial replacement of the discovery and mapping tool https://labs.portcullis.co.uk/tools/enum4linux/?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?  If you fill out more detail, it might be possible without doing this.

Comment: basically re-implement enum4linux.pl - https://labs.portcullis.co.uk/tools/enum4linux/